# Using Pandas to calculate quantities

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner in data science and I've started learning to use pandas not long ago. I'm currently doing a project, whose aim is to predict stock / Forex price using various quantities and their recent history as features in a neural network.

One of the quantities I'm considering using is the Hilbert Transform of the closing prices, and I've found the algorithm (pseudocode) given by Ehlers in his book [1] as

```
alpha1 = (cos(sqrt(0.5)*360/48) + sin(sqrt(0.5)*360/48) - 1) / cos(sqrt(0.5)*360/48)
hp = (1=0.5*alpha1)**2 * (close-2*close[1]+close[2]) + 2*(1-alpha1)*hp[1] - (1-alpha1)**2*hp[2]

a1 = exp(-sqrt(2)*pi / LPPeriod)
b1 = 2*a1*cos(sqrt(2)*180 / LPPeriod)
c2 = b1
c3 = -a1**2
c1 = 1 - c2 - c3
Filt = 0.5*c1*(hp + hp[1]) + c2*Filt[1] + c3*Filt[2]

IPeak = 0.991*IPeak[1]
if abs(Filt) > Ipeak:
    IPeak = abs(Filt)
Real = Filt / IPeak

QFilt = Real - Real[1]
QPeak = 0.991*QPeak[1]
if abs(QFilt) > Qpeak:
    QPeak = abs(QFilt)
Imag = QFilt / QPeak
```

where numbers in square brackets mean data from two days ago. For instance, `hp[2]` would be equivalent to `hp.shift(2, fill_value=0)` in pandas. Moreover, the default value of all variables are 0 apart from that of `LPPeriod`, which is 20.

My problem comes from the calculation of `Real`. How should I translate the block into pandas? Thanks in advance!

Reference:
[1] Ehlers, J. F. *Cycle Analytics for Traders*, John Wiley & Sons, Inc., 2013

Comment: could you explain what you're trying to do with 'Real' in terms of pandas?

Comment: I would like `Real` and `Imag` to be added as new columns to the dataframe, like `df['Real']`. If I know how to do `Real`, then `Imag` would follow naturally. Thanks, @triedit.

Answer (score 0):

To add those to the dataframe you should do:

```
df['Real'] = Real
df['Imag'] = Imag
```

Also make sure you call your functions on the columns.

Comment: Sorry, that I know, but the problem is that in the ```IPeak``` block, 
```IPeak = 0.991 * IPeak.shift(1, fill_value=0)```
but the first value is 0 by default, and the second value would depend on the first. The biggest problem is the if statement below. How can I do the if statement?

Comment: Currently the block of code reads: ```ipeak = hp*0 ; df['ipeak'] = np.where(np.abs(df['filt'])>0.991*df['ipeak'].shift(1, fill_value=0), np.abs(df['filt']), 0.991*df['ipeak'].shift(1, fill_value=0)) ; df['Hilbert_real'] = df['filt'] / df['ipeak']```

but the results are wrong.